java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'
Flutter package:  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^2.0.0.
I need a QR scanner in my flutter project so I install flutter_barcode_scanner and trying to test the example https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner/example.
When I run the this sample app, I am getting following exception:
D/nativeloader( 7609): Extending system_exposed_libraries: libedgetpu_dba.google.so
I/TFLite-in-PlayServices( 7609): Initialized module.
E/GoogleApiManager( 7609): Failed to get service from broker. 
E/GoogleApiManager( 7609): java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.
E/GoogleApiManager( 7609):  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3182)
E/GoogleApiManager( 7609):  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3166)
E/GoogleApiManager( 7609):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3149)
E/GoogleApiManager( 7609):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3091)

I have been researching around this for a day now and tried multiple ideas found on stackoverflow but the issue is still happening.
I am getting same error when testing on Pixel 3XL as well as Pixel 7.  Google Play services is up-to-date with version 24.10.17 on the pixel 7.
I have added following meta tags to Manifest as suggested in some posts:
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="24" />
   <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
      android:value="barcode" />

The issue is still happening.
Any suggestion is appreciated.
M.A

In my case, the solution was install the Google Repository and Google Play Services.
In Android Studio go to: Tools > SDK Manager > SDK Tools
Select the Google Repository and Google Play Services. click apply, wait to install, and click OK

